# How to pipe data over tcp from the command line?

Tags: windows, linux, command-line, tcp, pipe

I would like to pipe data from one machine in the command line to another machine over tcp. I guess I could write a socket server but this must already be implemented. *For example* I could use it to `xz` a file and send it over the network to the other side over a specified port, where I could decode and save it:

machine A: `strarc -c -d:c:/windows | xz -c -z - | magicsend -p 80 -h 192.168.1.100`
machine B: `magicreceive -p 80 | xz -d -f - | strarc -x -d:x:/windows`

I would like to do this in Linux *and/or* Windows with open-source tools. So Linux tools that have a[n unofficial] Windows port are preferable. :)

A working example command line is much appreciated.

*(Note that on a Linux example I would do `cat /vmlinuz` instead of [strarc](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/), sure it's not quite equivalent. ;) )*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use netcat. See the "CLIENT/SERVER" section of "man netcat". One machine B:

```
nc -l 1234 | xz -c > sammy.xz
```

and on machine A:

```
cat sammy | nc 192.168.1.100 1234
```

Note that there can be security implications to leaving ports open in this manner.

As [mpy](https://superuser.com/users/195224/mpy) points out, it is more efficient in terms of network bandwidth to compress on the sending side:

```
xz -c sammy | nc 192.168.1.100 1234
```

And just save on the receiving side:

```
nc -l 1234 > sammy.xz
```

Comment: works quite well, however for some reason this just won't exit for me after `sammy` is fully read. I think it's `netcat`. Can it be [the implementation I use](http://joncraton.org/blog/46/netcat-for-windows) causing the problem, or is this netcat's *design*, thus expected? Can I make it somehow exit once *sammy* is read ([EOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file)), (to arbitrary file sizes and reading times)?

Comment: @naxa: Hmm.. not clear why this should be. I don't have Windows handy but all of the documentation seems to say that also on Windows the server (B) should exit after the client (A) finishes writing to the pipe. can you post your commands? Sure you are using -l and not -L?

Comment: I'm puzzled, why you use xz on receiver's side?! It would be much more efficient, if you compress on sender (machine A): `xz -c sammy | nc 192.168.1.100 1234` and inflate on receiver (machine B): `nc -l 1234 | xzcat > sammy` and IMHO the intention of OP.

Comment: @mpy: I appended your comment to my answer, thanks.

Comment: I appreciate that, already upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

[Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) should suit your needs; I don't have the documentation handy so can't be certain, but I think the sending side's command would be `[...] | nc -h192.168.1.100 -p80`, while the receiving side would use `nc -l -p80 | [...]`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to remote log in to at least one of the machines (to run either magicsend or magicreceive) could you just use ssh?

ssh clients are easy to come by on Windows (just install cygwin, for example.)  ssh servers are also easy to come by, but may be harder to install/configure.

something like this if you are currently on the console of machine A and machine B is remote:

machine A: `strarc whatever | xz -c -z - | ssh me@machineB '(xz -d -f - | strarc somethingelse)'`

or if you are on the console of machine B and need to remote login to machine A then:

machine B: `ssh me@machineA '(strarc whatever | xz -c -z -)' | xz -d -f - | strarc somethingelse`

Comment: `but may be harder to install/configure` out of curiosity did you do this? I did with cygwin and it felt kind of limited and cumbersome.